# 1px gap when positioning absolute inside a display table element in chrome

Tags: layout, css

This is my first question here.

I was trying to get an element vertically aligned inside a parent with fixed width and height. Inside the parent box there is also a header, that needs to be absolutely positioned in the bottom.

When working on it, checking cross browser issues I saw a difference on chrome. In FF, IE 8 & 9 it works as it should, if you open the sample in Chrome (19 right now) it gives a 1px gap to the parent as you may see.

[Interactive example of the problem - CSSDeck](http://cssdesk.com/yq74n)

[How I see it - 1px gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL3u3.png)

I have tried removing white space, and quite a few things but I couldn't get to remove that gap...

Is this a bug? If you could help me remove the gap, or achieve the same result in a clean way that works cross browser (ie8+) it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tnRem/

Basically I removed `display: table` from `#outer` and set `height: 250px` and `box-sizing: border-box;` (only for IE8+) to `#inner`.

I tried it with Chrome 19.0.1084.46, Fx12 and IE8

Comment: Hey! messing with your solution I found something simpler [http://cssdesk.com/qDZgv](http://cssdesk.com/qDZgv) Thanks for your help!!